# Not able to delete an entry source in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a journey and associated an entry source to it. But now I would like to edit the entry schedule in entry source and it won't let me change it. I can see editing the entry source's schedule time is possible but after saving changes are not taking effect.

I have detached the entry source from journey and tried editing it. not possible.

I have tried copying to entry source and creating a new one but not able to delete the previous one, or the newer one.

Is there a way to delete the entry source, there is a delete button but when i hit delete nothing happens.

Comment: Are all journey versions using this entry event already stopped and don't have any remaining contacts in it?

Comment: This event source is not used by any other journey and just to point out I have also created a test event and tried deleting it but had no luck deleting it also.

Comment: Is there any message visible in your browser's developer tools network tab when inspecting the route that is called on deletion? Usually the direct response of the api-route in the background gives more helpful information than the marketing cloud user interface.

Comment: Hey in your previous comment I figured out a way and it worked. I went in to the newly created entry source and reedited it and this time I deselected the data extension selected and then tried deleting the entry source.. and tadaa.. it was deleted.. but wondering if it is possible to edit the entry source which I selected earlier? it s not editable as it shows 1 interaction even after I have removed it from the original journey

Comment: I had a similar issue once and stopping the version using the event and creating and saving a new version of the journey without an entry event made the entry event edit- and deletable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

All I was trying to do was to edit my entry source not create a new version, and fortunately I found a solution by creating a temporary entry source.

As the journey was already a draft, I detached the entry source without creating a new version and attached the temporary source to the journey and when I did that. the original entry source was editable as it was showing 0 interaction and issue was resolved.

Hope this helps people :) Thanks for all your efforts